# SQL2008 Express Edition: two instances on same computer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

Can we installed two instances of Express edition? 
I have one instance installed and when I try to install 2nd one, Product Key page/optionbs is grayed out (Specify Free Eidtion / Enter Prod. Key)

Is it by design or due to something I am missing here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum limit to the number of SQL Server Express instances is 16 on the same machine. These instances must be uniquely named for the purpose of identifying them.

Comment: May you share a link to the source of that quote? Thanks.

Comment: by googlin there are many links, like http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH62586

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can install Sql Express for multiple instances.

To install a new instance, please make sure you do a Custom installation and set a different name for the new instance.

The full Sql Express features can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).
As you can see, Multi-Instance support is set to YES